# Почему render выполняеться перед componentWillMount?

Tags: reactjs, redux

```js
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {bindActionCreators} from "redux";
import FilterModels from './FilterModels';
import {getTypes} from '../../actions/AjaxDataActions';

class FilterForm extends Component {

  constructor(props) {

    super(props);

  }

  async componentWillMount(){

               console.log( 1 );
    await this.props.getTypes(this.props.params, this.props.api) ;
    console.log( 2 );

  }


  render() {

    console.log( 3 )

    return (
      <div>
        <FilterModels/>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

function matchDispatchToProps(dispatch) {

  return bindActionCreators({
    getTypes: getTypes
  }, dispatch);
}

export default connect(
  state => ({
    api: state.api,
    params: state.ajaxData
  }), matchDispatchToProps)(FilterForm);
```

код action:

```js
export const getTypes = (object, api) => {
  return async dispatch => {
    await axios.post(api.url + api.transports + '/' + api.type)
      .then(response => {
        dispatch({
          type: UPDATE_AJAX_PARAMS,
          payload: response.data
        });
      });
  }

};
```

по идеи console.log должен рисовать 1->2->3, а на практике - 1,3,2

Вопрос - что не так с кодом и как исправить?

Answer (score 1):

> Конструкции, построенные с использованием async/await, как и промисы, не блокируют главный поток выполнения программы.

1. `componentWillMount` вызывается перед `render`. Но вы сделали его асинхронным. В лог успевает вывестись "1". Асинхронный процесс, не прерывает хода программы, поэтому...
2. Выполняется `render`. В консоль пишется "3".
3. В асинхронном процессе выполняются действия после await. В лог пишется "2"

Ну и напомню, что `componentWillMount` уже является **deprecated**

Comment: а как можно обойти такое и сначала получить данные, а потом отрендерить компонент после получения данных от сервера?

Comment: Ну, вроде нормальной практикой является что-то типа `render () { if (!this.props.params) return null; /* code */ }` (рендер запустится, но за неимением нужных пропсов вернет `null`

Comment: _сначала получить данные_ в рендере запускаете прогрессбар, а как данные получены - отрисовываете их